# ubuntu - GNU-RADIO - cmake could not find MPIR

Tags: ubuntu, cmake, gnuradio, gnuradio-companion, rtl-sdr

I'm trying to get a RTL-SDR source block (or osmo sdr, since they both work) in GNU Radio, and it apparently must be obtained via the following command lines:

```
git clone git://git.osmocom.org/gr-osmosdr
cd gr-osmosdr/

mkdir build
cd build/
cmake ../
```

I do as suggested, but when I run the last line I get the following error

```
No package 'mpir' found
-- Could NOT find MPIR (missing: MPIRXX_LIBRARY MPIR_LIBRARY MPIR_INCLUDE_DIR)
```

Among others:

```
Checking for module 'fftw3f >= 3.0'
Found fftw3f , version 3.3.8
 Found FFTW3f: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3f.so  
 Checking for module 'libosmodsp'
   No package 'libosmodsp' found
 libosmodsp not found.
 libosmodsp not found, using local checkout
 Could NOT find Doxygen (missing: DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE) 
 Using install prefix: /usr/local
 Building for version: 3.8.0.0 / 3.8.0
 No C++ unit tests... skipping 
 Checking for module SWIG
 Disabling SWIG because version check failed.
CMake Error at lib/CMakeLists.txt:30 (add_library):
  Cannot find source file:

    /home/hubp/Downloads/libosmo-dsp/src/cxvec.c

  Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .cu .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm
  .hpp .hxx .in .txx


CMake Error at lib/CMakeLists.txt:30 (add_library):
  No SOURCES given to target: gnuradio-iqbalance


CMake Generate step failed.  Build files cannot be regenerated correctly.
```

I suspect I might be missing some dependencies but I can't understand what they are or how to get them. Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I got it!

This guy goes over the required libraries

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2IWtEkAHXFI

I was missing swig, and afterwards I was also missing liborc-0.4-dev

They can be installed via:

```
sudo apt-get install swig
sudo apt install liborc-0.4-dev
```

Please note that despite helping my case in particular, this video predates the release of GNU Radio 3.8 by several years, and really does not reflect GNU Radio's current requirements.

Comment: That video is *very* badly outdated and does not reflect GNU Radio build dependencies well. Please do **not** refer to random videos on youtube. Build documentation can be found on the official GNU Radio wiki, https://wiki.gnuradio.org. Also, `gr-osmosdr` is not a command.

Comment: @MarcusMüller that might be true but that's how I solved the problem I was having, so I had the option of leaving this question unanswered or posting how I solved it and figured the latter would be more helpful. I would argue that it's not so obvious how one would solve such a problem by referring to the official build documentation or I would have done that instead of finding a random video...Thanks for pointing out my mistake regarding the "command", I have corrected it

Comment: you can't "run" gr-osmosdr on the command line; so your statement still doesn't make sense. And I don't know how far that video could have actually helped you or whether it was something else you figured out: That video predates the release of GNU Radio 3.8 by several years, and really *does not reflect GNU Radio's current requirements*.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Since it was over a week ago I don't remember what I ran exactly after ldconfig but I'll trust you that apparently it wasn't "gr-osmosdr" so I have removed that bit. I agree for sure that it's not the best source but that's what I used to figure out I was missing swig and maybe it will show somebody else what theyre missing, but I'll add a note with your heads up